# Legendary Card Game Kingpin card Pull the Strings

Tags: legendary-marvel

In the Legendary Card game, there is a hero character Kingpin who relies on new recruits to deal the largest portion of his damage/utility.

The way the card in question reads*

> Whenever a card effect causes you to gain a new recruit this turn, put that new recruit in your hand.
>
> Gain a new Recruit.

How exactly should a turn with 1 of these cards work, or even with 2. Do you play it, then just put a new recruit in your hand for the 2nd part of the card? then repeat for the 2nd pull the strings? or does your 2nd play the only one that gives you the new recruit to your hand?

I ask, because it seems the wording would just say-gain a new recruit-put any new recruit gained this turn into your hand-and it would be a lot less confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would play that card and gain a new recruit to your hand right away.

I think it is worded this way to differentiate between gaining a new recruit through a purchase and gaining it as the result of another card either purchased or gained through fight.

Also think of it as a way to keep it clear that the first part of the card still applies to all other cards played this turn or if other things trigger from gaining a new recruit that may be added in the future.